# Heroku - JavaEE - Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: architecture, heroku, twitter-bootstrap, java-ee-6, web-deployment

I have developed a JEE6 back-end application with a twitter-bootstrap frontend. GUI talks to back-end via REST. The original plan was to run GUI on apache and then have a Jboss cluster at back-end to offer scalability and HA...all running on Amazon EC2

I am now looking at Heroku as an alternative..it looks much simpler etc to manage, scale and so on. I am wondering what is the best way to convert my current architecture to suit Heroku's model?...for ex. somehow run the twitter-bootstrap GUI as a ruby app and somehow talk to existing Java ee app?

Important note! :-) ..

1. Our expertise is in JavaEE and our glaring weakness is web front end so be nice when describing front end alternatives.
2. Because of point 1. (and other time constraints) a complete redesign of GUI and switching from our twitter bootstrap GUI with all features it offers such as datatables is not an option!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku does not support **jboss**, **websphere** or **weblogic** type java application servers. There is no global "application container" between all dynos. Each dyno is isolated, so it needs to be able to bind to a port itself.

The typical way to think about it would be that your deployable process runs an embeddable webserver. Like jetty.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploy-a-java-web-application-that-launches-with-jetty-runner

Or that you use Webapp Runner to serve a tomcat based app.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-webapp-runner

On deploying two components, a heroku app can only bind to one port per app. Therefore create another heroku app. This gives the benefit of being able to update/deploy each part of the architecture independently and also scale them separately.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply David, one final query, in Herokus model, how do i 'tell' the GUI where the send the REST request to?

Comment: Through some means of application configuration. Recommendation would be via an **Environment** (ENV) variable.